# Volume scattering is limited by the fire simulation domain

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

- I have a scene with fire and smoke simulation, adaptive domain enabled .
- Fire is placed inside a cube with the volume scatter shader .

But the light scattering around the fire appears to be limited by the adaptive domain.

[image]

1) Why is this happening (the "air" should scatter light within the cube with "volume scatter" shader, instead of simulation domain)?

2) Can I fix it without removing the adaptive domain and stretching the primary domain to the size of the cube with the volume scatter shader?

(Imagine, if I have the torch in a large cave, it will take much longer to simulate the torch fire, if the domain will be extended to the whole scene, and taking into account the resolution of the simulation, which need to be increased because the domain is so big!)

Comment: I experimented a bit with it since I'm currently doing a project with fire and was curious. I'm guessing it's a bug and should be reported. The results just don't make any sense.

Comment: @Jbergman Thank you for the responce, yes, I think you're right, i'll report about it too.